# Android App crashes when attempting to execute Async Task

Tags: java, android, exception, android-asynctask, resources

My app crashes when it tries to execute on an AsyncTask I've created.

Basically I'm trying to get my Task to decode a bitmap from a given ResID and draw it on a canvas by passing it a container parameter.

Below is the relevant section of the code:

```
    class BitmapWorker extends AsyncTask<MyTaskParams, Void, Void> {

        private Canvas canvas;
        private Paint paint;
        private BitmapFactory.Options opt;
        private View view;

        public BitmapWorker(Canvas canvas, Paint paint, View view) {
            this.canvas = canvas;
            this.paint = paint;
            this.view = view;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(MyTaskParams... params) {
            Bitmap bmp;
            opt.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            opt.inPurgeable = true;
            opt.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(opt, canvas.getWidth() / 16, canvas.getHeight() / 10);
            opt.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), params[0].resID,opt);
            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, params[0].x, params[0].y, paint);
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            view.invalidate();
        }
    }

......

public class mbbs extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

....

 @Override
        public void run() {
            Paint paint=new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            paint.setTextSize(30);
            while (running) {

                if (!holder.getSurface().isValid())
                    continue;
                Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
                canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
                BitmapWorker task=new BitmapWorker(canvas,paint,surfaceview);
                MyTaskParams params=new MyTaskParams((int)crossx,(int)crossy,R.drawable.crosshair);
                task.execute(params); //Crashes here
```

The logcat prints out the error exceptions as shown:

```
12-06 15:25:46.829    1632-1645/android.process.acore E/DictionaryBackupAgent﹕ Couldn't read from the cursor
12-06 15:26:34.228    1632-1641/android.process.acore E/StrictMode﹕ A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
    java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
            at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
            at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:180)
            at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:916)
            at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:906)
            at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:57)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
12-06 15:26:34.229    1632-1641/android.process.acore E/StrictMode﹕ A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
    java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
            at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
            at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:180)
            at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:916)
            at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:906)
            at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:64)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
12-06 15:26:34.229    1632-1641/android.process.acore E/StrictMode﹕ A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
    java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
            at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
            at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:180)
            at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:916)
            at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:906)
            at android.app.IBackupAgent$Stub.onTransact(IBackupAgent.java:71)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:446)
```

I've attempt to Google but all it says is something about Strict Mode or not releasing any resources. However,I'm not really sure what resources I'm supposed to release.

Thanks.

Comment: Your AsyncTask need to be called from the UI thread. Also you must close strea, that you left open cause it leads to memory leaks.

Comment: You can always enable strict mode. StrictMode.setVmPolicy(new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder().detectAll().penaltyLog()
                                .penaltyDeath().build());

Comment: Hi, I thought it already is executing in the UI thread? How do I get it to execute in the UI thread?

Comment: Also, what do u mean by the strea that I need to close?

Comment: Are you calling runOnUiThread(new Runnable) or handler.post(runnable)? I cannot see that in your code... And I meant some url connections that you left open

Comment: Hi I've edited it to show the location of the Runnable. The run() method is part of the class implementing the Runnable. However, when I try to move  the task.execute out of run() to the main class, it turns red and flags an error.(cannot resolve symbol execute)

Comment: Is there any way to check for open connections?Thanks